# Overconcentration of Poles on the Circle of Convergence of a Power Series with Bounded Coefficients

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, asymptotics, power-series

Let $V$ be an arbitrary set of infinitely many positive integers, and let: $$\varsigma_{V}\left(z\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\sum_{v\in V}z^{v}$$ Let $T_{V}$ denote the set of all $t\in\left[0,1\right)$ for which the limit:

$$c_{V}\left(t\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\lim_{x\uparrow1}\left(1-x\right)\varsigma_{V}\left(e^{2\pi it}x\right)$$
exists and is non-zero. Is $T_{V}$ necessarily finite (that is, would an "overconcentration" of radii on which $\varsigma_{V}\left(z\right)$ grows like $\frac{1}{1-\left|z\right|}$ as $z$ tends radially to the unit circle result in a contradiction against the boundedness of $\varsigma_{V}\left(z\right)$'s power series coefficients)? Or do there exist $V$ for which $T_{V}$ is infinite?

Part of the problem is that there is *so much* literature about the boundary behavior and singularities of power series that trying to find information about something this specific is like looking for the needle in the proverbial haystack. Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The set can be infinite (but only countable). For an example choose any $t_j$ linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$ and let $V$ be the set of all $v$ such that $vt_j\mod 1 \notin (\frac 12-a_j,\frac 12+a_j)$ for all $1\le j\le J(v)$ where $a_j$ decrease so fast that $\sum_j a_j<+\infty$ and the function $J$ increases to $+\infty$ so slowly that by the moment $v_0$ it reaches $j_0$ you may say that $e^{2\pi ivt_j}$ for $v=1,\dots,v_0$ model the joint distribution of $j_0$ independent variables equidistributed over the unit circle with high precision. That (with some small extra care and effort) will give you the existence of non-zero limits even for Cesaro means and the Poisson summation method is stronger.

**Edit** (about the sum of squares). Let us assume that the limit $L_j=c(t_j)$ exists for some finite collection of $t_j$. Consider 
$$
L=\lim_{x\to 1}\sum_j \bar L_j(1-x)\sum_{v>0}\chi_V(v)x^ve^{2\pi i t_j v}\,.
$$
On the one hand, $L=\sum|L_j|^2$. On the other hand, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
L^2\le \limsup_{x\to 1}\left[(1-x)\sum_{v>0}\chi_V(v)^2x^v\right]
\left[(1-x)\sum_{v>0}\left|\sum_j\bar L_j e^{2\pi i t_j v}\right|^2 x^v\right]
$$
The expression in the first brackets is at most $1$, while, if you open the absolute value and take into account that 
$$
(1-x)\sum_{v>0}e^{2\pi i (t_j-t_k) v} x^v\to 0
$$
for $j\ne k$, you'll find that the limit of the sum in the second brackets is $L$. That gives $L^2\le L$, so $L\le 1$.

Apologies to everybody for endless edits. Here comes another one.

Consider a very fast increasing sequence $n_k$, $k\ge 1$ of positive integers (as usual, that means that we will choose them inductively). Let $N_k=\prod_{m=1}^k(2^{n_m}-1)$.

Define $V_k$ as the set of $v\ge 1$ congruent to $N_{k-1}2^\alpha$ modulo $N_k$ with some $\alpha\in\{0,1,\dots,n_k-1\}$ (we define $N_0=1$). It is clear that we just take $n_k$ possible residues modulo $N_k$, so the density of $V_k$ is $n_k/N_k$.

Put $V=\cup_{k\ge 1} V_k$ and $t_k=N_k^{-1}$. That's the whole construction. Now it remains to explain why it works.

First, $V_k$ are disjoint. Indeed, if $m<k$, all elements of $V_k$ are divisible by $N_m$ but no element of $V_m$ is.

Second, $V_k$ is $N_k$-periodic, so even the Cesaro averages $L_k(z,M)=\frac 1{M}\sum_{v\in V_k,v\le M}z^{v}$  have limits for all $z=e^{2\pi it}\in\mathbb T$ (we will always assume this relation between $z$ and $t$).

Third, $\max_M\frac{|V_k\cap[1,M]|}{M}=N_{k-1}^{-1}$, so as long as the series $\sum_{k\ge 1}N_{k-1}^{-1}$ converges, we can safely claim that the limit 
$L(z)=\lim_{M\to\infty}L(z,M)=\lim_{M\to\infty}\frac 1{M}\sum_{v\in V,v\le M}z^{v}$ exists and equals $\sum_{k\ge 1} L_k(z)$ ($L_k(z)$ are defined similarly with $V_k$ instead of $V$).

Fourth, each $V_k$ satisfies the property that if $v\in V_k$, then $2v\in V_k$ and, provided that $v$ is even, $\frac v2\in V_k$. Thus
$$
\{2v:v\in V_k\}=\{v\in V_k: v\text{ is even}\}\,.
$$

Since for every $M$, we have $L_k(z,M)+L_k(-z,M)=\frac 2M\sum_{v\in V_k, v\text{ even}, v\le M}z^v=\frac 2M\sum_{v\in V_k, v\le M/2}z^{2v}=L_k(z^2,M/2)$, we conclude passing to the limit as $M\to\infty$ that $L_k(z)+L_k(-z)=L_k(z^2)$ for all $k$ and, thereby $L(z)+L(-z)=L(z^2)$.

Fifth, if $t=N_{k}^{-1}$, then $L_m(z)=0$ for $m<k$ (just because $V_m$ is $N_m$-periodic and $N_k>N_m$, but 
$$
L_k(z)=N_k^{-1}\sum_{\alpha=0}^{n_k-1}e^{2\pi i\frac{2^\alpha}{2^{n_k}-1}}\ne 0
$$ 
(all terms are in one half-plane) and $L_m(z)$ with $m>k$ cannot change that because they are ridiculously small (at most $n_m/N_m$) compared to anything depending on $n_1,\dots, n_k$ only (it is this condition that forces the fast growth of $n_k$). Thus $L(z)\ne 0$.

Comment: How would one go about showing that $T_{V}$ must be countable? Also, what would happen if $T_{V}$ is required to contain only rational numbers? Also, also, any links or references you could give me on the matter would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @MCS The sum of squares of limits is finite. For "only rational numbers" I'll have to think for a (possibly long) while. I doubt there is something exactly dealing with your question, but if you look at the literature devoted to almost periodic functions, you'll find all necessary tricks there.

Comment: [The sum of squares of limits is finite] - - - Sorry for being dense (again), but, I don't quite see how that follows. 

Almost periodic functions. Got it. That will help. Thank you—both for what you've done, and anything else you might still do. :)

Comment: Using the other things I'm working with, I think I've gotten a proof of what I'm looking for. Let  $R\left(t\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\lim_{x\uparrow1}\left(1-x\right)\varsigma_{V}\left(e^{2\pi it}x\right)$. I've been able to show that there is an infinite subset $S_{V}\subseteq T_{V}$ so that $R$ is constant on $S_{V}$. By your remark about the sum of the squares, this forces $\sum_{t\in S_{V}}\left|R\left(t\right)\right|^{2}<\infty$, and so $R\left(t\right)=0$ on $S_{V}$, a contradiction. I'd be really grateful if you could explain to me how to prove the sum of the squares is 0. :)

Comment: @MCS Done. Feel free to ask questions if something is unclear.

Comment: Brilliant! I always forget about the series analogue of Cauchy-Schwarz. All the abstract analysis that gets stuffed down our faces nowadays in school really obscures the connections between the theorems and their divers applications in "real life" situations like this. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you're still interested in the case where $T_{V}$ contains only rational numbers... it turns out my proof didn't work. You've been tremendous helpful so far, so I don't want to impose any more than I already have, but... I'll admit, I'm pretty desperate here. No matter what, though, thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: @MCS I can think of it more but nothing is guaranteed. So what exactly is your setup?

Comment: Change perspective from the disk to the half plane; write $\psi_{V}\left(z\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\sum_{v\in V}e^{2v\pi iz}$. Instead of radial limits, consider the function $R\left(t\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\lim_{y\downarrow0}iy\psi_{V}\left(iy+t\right)$. Let $T_{V}$ denote the set of all $t\in\mathbb{Q}$ for which $R\left(t\right)$ exists, and suppose that $R\left(2t\right)=R\left(t\right)+R\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ holds for all $t\in T_{V}$. I want to show that $T_{V}$ is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e., $T_{V}\cap\left[0,1\right]$ is finite).

Comment: Erm... When you state the property the way you did, do you mean that the existence of $R(t)$ implies the existence of $R(t+\frac 12)$ and $R(2t)$ or something weaker or stronger than that? Also, we still assume that $R(t)\ne 0$ for $t\in T_V$, right?

Comment: In writing, $R\left(2t\right)-R\left(t+\frac{1}{2}\right)=R\left(t\right)$ for all $t\in T_{V}$, it means that: $$\lim_{y\downarrow0}\left(iy\psi_{V}\left(iy+2t\right)-iy\psi_{V}\left(iy+t+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)=\lim_{y\downarrow0}iy\psi_{V}\left(iy+t\right)$$

Comment: As for the non-vanshing, I goofed! $T_{V}$ is the set of all $t$ for which $R\left(t\right)$ exists; I want to show that the *subset* $S_{V}\subseteq T_{V}$ on which $R\left(t\right)\neq0$ is discrete (Sorry for the confusion).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that this is just the simplest case; the general case is: $$R\left(t\right)=R\left(Nt\right)-\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}e^{\frac{2n\pi i}{N}}R\left(t+\frac{n}{N}\right)$$ I'll admit: I'm curious to see what the difference would be if we went in with the asumption that each individual term exists for all $t\in T_{V}$, as opposed to what happens when it is merely assumed that both sides exist, rather than the individual terms. Although, a proof for the weaker assumptions would be best. Anyhow, thanks again. :)

Comment: Also, we can assume that $R\left(0\right)$ exists and is non-zero. And, just to be clear, $T_{V}$ is still a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. (Okay, self, time for bed now. xD)

Comment: @MSC Unfortunately, just assuming rationality is not enough. Your property should be crucial in some way if the desired result holds. It will take me some time to comprehend the meaning of it...

Comment: Just to make sure you haven't misunderstand me: my argument makes no assumptions about whether or not there are irrational values of $t$ for which $R\left(t\right)$ exists. Like in your original counterexample, there could very well be a non-discrete set of irrational values of $t$ for which $R\left(t\right)$ exists and is non-zero, to boot. All I want is the discreteness of the set of *rational* values of $t$ for which $R\left(t\right)$ exists and is non-zero. My hope was that the fact that $\psi_{V}\left(z\right)'s$ coefficients were only 0 or 1 would be enough to prove this.

Comment: @MCS At this moment I can construct an example when 1) $R(t)$ exists for all $t$, 2) $R(2t)=R(t+\frac 12)+R(t)$ for all $t$, 3) There is a sequence $t_j$ of rational numbers tending to $0$ such that $R(t_j)\ne 0$. If this closes the story, I'll post it. Otherwise let me know if there is anything else that you know about $V$. :-)

Comment: Post it and let me take a look-see. :D Edit: Actually, wait. There is one more condition I can impose: V contains an infinite arithmetic progression (b, a+b, 2a+b, ...).

Comment: @MCS The last condition is not a restriction at all. OK, I will post the example today but somewhat later (have other fish to fry at the moment)

Comment: Take your time. :)

Comment: @MCS Posted....

Comment: This is awesome; you are awesome. I'll have to spend time going through this example in detail. That being said, I hope you don't mind if I take you up on your offer to ask more questions. :) For an arbitrary $V$, what can be said about the set of $t$ (in $\mathbb{Q}$, and in $\mathbb{R}$) for which $R\left(t\right)$ does or does not exist? For example, does $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq T_{V}$ imply $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq T_{V}$?—or, can there be infinitely many points (in $\mathbb{Q}$? in $\mathbb{R}$?) where $R\left(t\right)$ does not exist?

Comment: @MCS Have you read "Alice in Wonderland"? (or was it "Through the looking glass"?). There is a passage there where she recites "Father William" and I like the ending a lot ;-)) That was a joke, of course, but seriously, step back for a while and spend some time understanding what you really want to get and where it is all going. Once you have a clear picture of what you are after, I'll be happy to think of some concise question you may have (start a new thread then)  but now I'd rather fry some other fish. Still, you can always ask for clarifications on what has been posted already :-).

Comment: I'm using these functions to investigate matters in number theory. I call these functions "set-series", and use their analytical properties to deduce information about the set $V$ that they model. Knowing what is possible for generic set-series informs the  kinds of arguments I can('t) make. For example, my original question about the discreteness of $T_{V}$ has to do with the fact that I have an argument which works for set-series with that property. Dealing with generic cases, it helps to know what the possibilities are, rather than just taking things for granted. :)

Comment: @MCS OK, then think of what (im)possibilities interest you most and start a new thread. This one is cluttered enough IMHO ;-)

Comment: Here you go: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/334532/existence-of-radial-limits-of-products-of-certain-power-series-and-1-x